# How to search case insensitive wildcard query with Elastic Search in Java?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

```
BoolQueryBuilder paramFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    paramFilter.must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(field, "*"+key+"*"));
```

Can someone tell me how to use the caseInsensitive?

Comment: did you get a chance to look into my answer? its been really long, let me know if you have follow up question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the case_insensitive param introduced in 7.10 as described in [official documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "ki*y",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score",
        "case_insensitive" : true --> note this
      }
    }
  }
}
```